# Python - testing equality of coefficients in logit regression

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I am doing my first project in Python as a beginner.

I want to try and determine if two coefficients in a Logit Regression are significantly different from each other. Specifically, I am trying to do a Wald test, and I want to know how to calculate/display the variance-covariance matrix of the parameters after I have run the logit regression.

I have found the code and instructions in R how to do this, and would like some help doing it in Python. I am using the same UCLA data as used in the example answer here:  [Stats exchange post on doing Wald test using R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59085/how-to-test-for-simultaneous-equality-of-choosen-coefficients-in-logit-or-probit)

The code in R that runs what I am after is in the answer below:
“So we also need the covariance of βgreβgre and βgpaβgpa. The variance-covariance matrix can be extracted with the vcov command after running the logistic regression:
var.mat <- vcov(mylogit)[c("gre", "gpa"),c("gre", "gpa")]

colnames(var.mat) <- rownames(var.mat) <- c("gre", "gpa")

Is there some sort of equivalent to the vcov command mentioned above?

If not, are there other solutions I could easily implement to test if the coefficients are significantly different from each other?

Thank you for any help,
Matt

Comment: Your question fits better [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) at stats sister site of SO.

Comment: It's a programming question and will not be appropriate for stats.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the built-in features, then `results.t_test` for (vectorized) single hypotheses and `results.wald_test` for a joint hypothesis are available. All models except for the linear models use the normal and chisquare distribution for the Wald test, however this can be changed by the `use_t` and `use_f` keyword either in the test method or in `model.fit` method.

Both can take either a restriction or contrast matrix or a string that defines the hypotheses for the Null hypothesis. This is the same for essentially all models.

e.g. for Logit, although the doc string is generic and uses OLS in the example
http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.t_test.html

Likelihood Ratio and score or Lagrange multiplier tests are not generally implemented yet and are mainly available for the linear regression models.

For do it yourself, the covariance of the parameter estimates is available in the `results.cov_params()` method, as are all other required statistics. The negative loglikelihood is available as `results.llf` attribute in all Maximum Likelihood models.

Comment: Thank you for an amazing answer. I was able to get the .cov_params() method, results.t_test and results.wald_test methods all working.